# Grunt build - copy dist EISDIR warning

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-build-control

I have s problem with copy:dist operations in my Grunt build task.

In my copy:dist in src array I have inluded my styles directory:

'styles/{,**/**}*.{png,css,gif,otf,eot,svg,ttf,woff}',

and my files strucure is like this:
.../styles
.../styles/font/
.../styles/fontello/
.../styles/fontello/css
.../styles/fontello/font
.../styles/fonts/font-awesome
.../styles/fonts/glyphicons

When I run grunt build I get this error:
Warning: Unable to read "dist/styles/fonts/font-awesome" file (Error code: EISDIR)

BUT - if I rename styles/fonts/ to styles/fonts1/ everything works fine.

Why am I getting this problem? Because of folder name "fonts". Is it not allowed?

Thnaks for any idea why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
styles/**/*.{png,css,gif,otf,eot,svg,ttf,woff}
```